# How to run tests OL3 (Windows)?

Tags: windows, testing, build, cygwin, openlayers-3

Can not run tests via `npm test`:

```
    PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ol3> npm test

    > openlayers@3.17.1 pretest C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ol3
    > eslint tasks test test_rendering src examples


    > openlayers@3.17.1 test C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ol3
    > node tasks/test.js

    mocha.run() was called with no tests
    npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Ok, [advised](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5654) to read ["Building on Windows"](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#building-on-windows):

1. install Cygwin (`make` + `nano`)
2. edit Cygwin's `/etc/fstab` file to disable ACLs like this `none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,noacl,posix=0,user 0 0`
3. run make

```
    PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ol3> make test
    Не найден файл: *.glsl
    Не найден файл: *.js
    Не найден файл: *.js
    Не найден файл: *.js
    FIND: Неправильный формат параметра
    Не найден файл: *.html
    Не найден файл: *.js
    FIND: Неправильный формат параметра
    npm install
    \
    > openlayers@3.17.1 install C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ol3
    > node tasks/install.js


    > openlayers@3.17.1 postinstall C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ol3
    > closure-util update

    coveralls@2.11.12 node_modules\coveralls
    ├── lcov-parse@0.0.6
    ├── log-driver@1.2.4
    ├── minimist@1.2.0
    ├── js-yaml@3.0.1 (esprima@1.0.4, argparse@0.1.16)
    └── request@2.74.0 (aws-sign2@0.6.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, tunnel-agent@0.4.3, oauth-sign@0.8.2, is-typedarray@1.0.0, cas
    eless@0.11.0, stringstream@0.0.5, aws4@1.4.1, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, extend@3.0.0, tough-cookie@2.3.
    1, qs@6.2.1, node-uuid@1.4.7, combined-stream@1.0.5, mime-types@2.1.11, form-data@1.0.0-rc4, hawk@3.1.3, bl@1.1.2, http-
    signature@1.1.1, har-validator@2.0.6)
    node tasks/test.js
    mocha.run() was called with no tests
    make: *** [Makefile:136: test] Error 1
```

> Не найден файл = File not found
>   Неправильный формат параметра = Invalid parameter format

Oh, verify...

```
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ol3>make check
    Не найден файл: *.glsl
    Не найден файл: *.js
    Не найден файл: *.js
    Не найден файл: *.js
    FIND: Неправильный формат параметра
    Не найден файл: *.html
    Не найден файл: *.js
    FIND: Неправильный формат параметра
    Running eslint...
    node tasks/build.js config/ol.json build/ol.js
    info ol Parsing dependencies
    info ol Compiling 273 sources
    ERR! compile Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: TieredCompilation is disabled in this release.
    ERR! compile
    uncompressed: 483434 bytes
      compressed: 140119 bytes
    node tasks/test.js
    mocha.run() was called with no tests
    make: *** [Makefile:136: test] Error 1
```

Again **failure**!

How to run tests OL3 ?

Comment: T'he "File not found" errors indicate that you do are missing some js files, probably the ones that contain the tests. Did you clone git://github.com/openlayers/ol3.git and try to run the tests in the cloned folder?

Comment: Launch in the updated project folder of my fork. I see an error on the search mask, but not the file. Me may need something else to install component in Cygwin?